# How can I do automatic link and htmlspecialchars conversion at the same time?

Tags: php, regex

I want to create code that meets both of the following two things at the same time.

1. If text contains any url, the part is automatically converted to a `<a href ~ class='temp_class'>` link.
2. Apply the `func1()` to html entity characters on the text, except some  parts generated by the above function. (this is to prevent attack by malicious script.)

So I wrote the following code:

```
<?php
    function func1($text) //function like htmlspecialchars
    {
        $text = str_replace("&", "&#38;", $text);
        $text = str_replace("\"", "&#34;", $text);
        $text = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $text);
        $text = str_replace("<", "&#60;", $text);
        $text = str_replace(">", "&#62;", $text);
        $text = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $text);
        return $text;
    }
    function func2($text)
    {
        $text = func1($text);
        $url_pattern = "(http|https):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9.\/?&=%_+-@~:#$]+)";
        $text = preg_replace("/(".$url_pattern.")/i", "<a href='\\1' target='_blank' class='temp_class'>\\1</a>", $text);
        return $text;
    }
    $test_string ="hello universe! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=test     <iframe src='https://youtube.com/watch?v=good'></iframe> hello world.";
    echo func2($test_string);
?>
```

However, when I run the above code,  is applied 'too widely'. **In other words, 'https: //www.~' (...) '~ hello world' is treated as 'a single link'.**

What I wanted was three things:

1. `<a href ~ class='temp_class'>` applies to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=test
2. `<a href ~ class='temp_class'>` applies to https://youtube.com/watch?v=good
3. `<`, `>`, `'`, `etc.` in this text are appropriately converted by `func1()`. So `<iframe ~ ></iframe>` tag does not work.

1 and 2 are not operating normally.

I can guess why this is happening. Perhaps, `func1()` transforms `<`, `>`, `etc.` into `&#60;`, `&#62;`, `etc.`, so regexp in `func2()` interprets them as part of url.

I can guess why, but I do not know what to do now.

I'm considering adding some words to `$url_pattern` in `func2()` to exclude characters like `%nbsp;` or `&#60;` from being interpreted. However, how to express this with regexp is also a big hurdle to me.

I have spent a long time on this problem but it is very difficult. Please help me.

Please leave a comment if there is anything you cannot understand.

Comment: Use `htmlspecialchars`, don't write your own. Can you give some better use-cases for your linkifier? Have you looked for [existing implementations](https://getcomposer.org)?

Comment: Is this the output you'd like ? `hello&nbsp;universe!&nbsp;<a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=test' target='_blank' class='temp_class'>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=test</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#60;iframe&nbsp;src=&#39;<a href='https://youtube.com/watch?v=good' target='_blank' class='temp_class'>https://youtube.com/watch?v=good</a>&#39;&#62;&#60;/iframe&#62;&nbsp;hello&nbsp;world.`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `func1()` converts all spaces in `&nbsp;`, and so when there regular expression looks at the result, it sees to breaks - for example after `"hello"` the next character is `&` which is allowed in your regular expression.

You should run the URL capture regular expression before you do HTML escaping, and then do HTML escaping later.

BTW - do use `htmlspecialchars()` instead of your own custom function - as @tadman noted. One main advantage of that is that `htmlspecialchars()` does not convert spaces and so will not experience the problem you described, and also - converting spaces to non-breaking spaces is not a good idea in general.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try this. Guards against entities within the url.

[Formatted regex](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 ( https? )                    # (1)
 : //
 (                             # (2 start)
      (?:
           (?!
                (?i)
                (?:
                     &
                     (?:
                          [a-z_:] [a-z\d_:.-]* 
                       |  (?:
                               \#
                               (?: [0-9]+ | x [0-9a-f]+ )
                          )
                     )
                  |  % [a-z_:] [a-z\d_:.-]* 
                )
                ;
           )
           [a-zA-Z0-9./?&=%_+-@~:#$] 
      )+
 )                             # (2 end)
```

Php
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0bba1854a960c00d4946b9cdaa9cca2ca2e447fc

```
<?php
    function func1($text) //function like htmlspecialchars
    {
        $text = str_replace("&", "&#38;", $text);
        $text = str_replace("\"", "&#34;", $text);
        $text = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $text);
        $text = str_replace("<", "&#60;", $text);
        $text = str_replace(">", "&#62;", $text);
        $text = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $text);
        return $text;
    }
    function func2($text)
    {
        $text = func1($text);
        $url_pattern = "(http|https):\/\/((?:(?!(?i)(?:&(?:[a-z_:][a-z\d_:.-]*|(?:\#(?:[0-9]+|x[0-9a-f]+)))|%[a-z_:][a-z\d_:.-]*);)[a-zA-Z0-9.\/?&=%_+-@~:#$])+)";
        $text = preg_replace("/(".$url_pattern.")/i", "<a href='\\1' target='_blank' class='temp_class'>\\1</a>", $text);
        return $text;
    }
    $test_string ="hello universe! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=test     <iframe src='https://youtube.com/watch?v=good'></iframe> hello world.";
    echo func2($test_string);
```

Output (with extra newline spacing)

```
hello&nbsp;universe!&nbsp;

<a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=test' target='_blank' class='temp_class'>
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=test
</a>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#60;iframe&nbsp;src=&#39;

<a href='https://youtube.com/watch?v=good' target='_blank' class='temp_class'>
https://youtube.com/watch?v=good
</a>

&#39;&#62;&#60;/iframe&#62;&nbsp;hello&nbsp;world.
```